# Graphing in SAS

Tags: sas

New to SAS so please bear with me. :) I'm trying to graph an output table with three y variables and one x. I've tried gplot and plot, however, I'm still getting iffy results and I can't figure out how to make them all show in one graph either :( I think my table is too large for pasting here so I uploaded to office.com and hopefully, someone smarter than I can figure this out.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnxXzVHJV4pKghj1MoJoWOQxzYTd?e=cJ1J5y

Answer (score 1):

Use three `SERIES` statements in `SGPLOT`

Example:

```
data have;
  do x = -10 to 10 by .1;
    y1 = x**2 / 10;
    y2 = 4 * sin ( x / 5 );
    y3 = x;
    output;
  end;
run;

ods html file='plot.html' style=plateau;

proc sgplot data=have;
  series x=x y=y1;
  series x=x y=y2;
  series x=x y=y3;
run;

ods html close;
```

Output:
[image]

The old school `Proc GPLOT` would use the `PLOT / OVERLAY` option:

```
goptions reset=all;
symbol value=none interpol=join;

proc gplot data=have;
  plot (y1-y3) * x / overlay;   /* ( list of y-variables ) * x-variable */
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`proc sgplot` might be what you are looking for.

https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/154-2010.pdf

It is not clear from the link or question what exactly you are looking for but if I had to guess I would say this would certainly help.